# null value in column violates not-null constraint while saving ModelForm

Tags: python, django, modelform

I have a model which extends the `User` model of django like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model): 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name="user details")
    rewardpoints = models.IntegerField("rewardpoints") 

    def __str__(self):  
          return "%s's profile" % self.user.username
```

my forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['rewardpoints']

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

my view.py

```
class UserProfileFormView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        userform = UserForm(request.POST, prefix='users')
        userprofileform = UserProfileForm(request.POST, prefix='userprofiles')
        if userform.is_valid() and userprofileform.is_valid():
            new_user = userform.save() #### Error over here.
            new_userprofile = userprofileform.save(commit=False)
            new_userprofile.user = new_user
            new_userprofile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:welcome'))
        else:
            userform = UserForm(prefix='users')
            userprofileform = UserProfileForm(prefix='userprofiles')
            return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'user_form': userform, 'userprofile_form': userprofileform})
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        userform = UserForm(prefix='users')
        userprofileform = UserProfileForm(prefix='userprofiles')    
        return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'user_form': userform, 'userprofile_form': userprofileform})
```

my signup.html

```
<p> Hello Signup!! </p>
<form action="{% url 'users:signup' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ user_form.username.label_tag }}
{{ user_form.username }}
{{ user_form.password.label_tag }}
{{ user_form.password }}
{{ userprofile_form }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</html>
```

But while making the post request, there is this error: `null value in column "rewardpoints" violates not-null constraint`

Please show me a way out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because your field `rewardpoints` needs some value, it can't be null, so, or pass a value to rewardpoint through your form  or you can set a default value to it(Recommended). Then when you create a userprofile, form will set 0 as initial value.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model): 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name="user details")
    rewardpoints = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: Thanks @levi for your reply. This works. But now, it gives me another error: ntegrityError at /users/signup/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_userprofile_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(20) already exists.

Could you please give me some lead?

Comment: Although the data have been stored in the database. The error seems to be at new_userprofile.save()

Comment: @Abhishek you are trying to insert a user with id 20 twice, and  user's id must be unique, clean your database or refresh the page and create a new user.

Comment: Event after running flush on the project, I am getting the error. :( I have got to be missing something.

Comment: @Abhishek you are trying to create a user with the same id, if you can delete your data,  clean up your database.

Comment: @Abhishek if you still have the problem, you can open a new question, I think this is answered, you can mark my answer as correct by clicking on check mark.